# go back to the previous activity when clicked on back button in android

Tags: android

I am designing a login based application.i have applied on click on the submit button to go to next view.In the nextview i have back button.I want that when i click on back button view should go back to previous activity

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: do u have a back button in your activty or you pressed device's back key ?

Comment: i have a back button in my activity yaar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chirag answer is what I would do, but correct me if I am wrong...

Wouldn'it be better to add the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityB.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
ActivityA.this.startActivity(i);
```

that's hat I currently use in my application and would be sure that's a good idea.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

simply use **finish()** method it will take back to previous activity.